# Season as a verb?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I was watching a video and I heard this phrase:

> If desired, season the hot plate griddle after wiping.

I wanted to know what this verb exactly means and when to use it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? Or thinking about the word seasoning/seasonings, you know, like salt and pepper, garlic, etc.

Comment: Yes, but in the context it makes no sense. The dictionary and online bring me only definitions of the noun season and what you said.

Comment: [*Season* as a verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/season) (scroll down the page a bit).

Comment: Not this @AndrewLeach. Also why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but the tooltip on the arrow says "This question does not show any research effort..." If you found that and it didn't make any sense, you should include it in your question.

Comment: @MucaP You are quite right. I am very surprised that this does not appear in any of the major dictionaries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasoning_(cookware)

Comment: See also https://www.charbroil.com/community/how-to-season-your-char-broil-grill/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I found the meaning:

> Seasoning is a process by which oil is baked into metal to create a stick resistant surface and protect against oxidization. Blackstone Griddles come with a thin layer of soy oil on them to protect against rust during shipping. This may leave some blemishes and discoloration on your griddle top. This is normal and will all even out during the seasoning process.

Comment: Surely this is a context-dependant question. Yes, season can be used as a verb. However, this could be mean to season prior to adding food?